# spark read a text with multiple new character

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a csv file which has a comment field. The text has new line characters in it. When I use CSV's multiLine option still a new row gets created if there are more than 1.

Below is the code and data(sample but similar to actual)

package sample.spark.com;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog;
import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class IndividualApp {

    
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndividualApp.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("IndividualApp").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
        
        session.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");
        
        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
        
        options.put("inferSchema", "true");
        options.put("header", "true");
        options.put("multiLine","true");
        
        Dataset<Row> df = session.read().options(options).csv("C:\\DataSet\\sample.csv");
        
        df.show(Boolean.FALSE);

        
        
        
        
        df = df.groupBy("id").count().orderBy(functions.col("id").desc());
        
        df.show(Boolean.FALSE);
        

        
        logger.info("THE VALUE IS "+df.count());
        
        
        

    }

}
```

Output

```
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID                                           |comment                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1                                            |"Added business Added 80/60/1300; 
200/100/1800-Name change from ""Added|
|Added Added Added - 311/271/1911 Added/Added"|null                                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+


+---------------------------------------------+-----+
|id                                           |count|
+---------------------------------------------+-----+
|Added Added Added - 311/271/1911 Added/Added"|1    |
|1                                            |1    |
+---------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Data

```
ID , comment
1 , Added business Added 80/60/1300; 
200/100/1800-Name change from "Added, Added Added for Added Added Added."-Added-Added; 
Added Added Added - 311/271/1911 Added/Added
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue as it produces more records than actual numbers. I solution that I thought was to ignore any value id column that contains string but this wont work if comments have only numbers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by adding below code .I don't know how it worked but it worked for me

("escape", """);